# Select All Columns Except the Ones I Transformed?

Tags: dbt

Apologies,

I am still a beginner at DBT. Is there a way to select all the columns that I didn't explicitly put in my select statement? Something like this:

```
{{ config(materialized='view') }}

with my_view as (
    select
        TO_DATE(SOME_DATE_FIELD, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss AM') AS SOME_DATE_FIELD,
        {{ -- do something that gets the other columns from my_db.my_schema.my_table }}
    from my_db.my_schema.my_table
),

final as (
    select * from my_view
)

select * from final
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use BigQuery or DuckDB, you can use [`* except` (BQ)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_except) or `* exclude` (DuckDB). That would look like this:

```sql
...
with my_view as (
    select
        TO_DATE(SOME_DATE_FIELD, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss AM') AS SOME_DATE_FIELD,
        * except (SOME_DATE_FIELD)
    from my_db.my_schema.my_table
),
...
```

If you're on a different dialect, you can use the [`star` macro in `dbt_utils`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#star-source), which would look like this:

```sql
with my_view as (
    select
        TO_DATE(SOME_DATE_FIELD, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss AM') AS SOME_DATE_FIELD,
        {{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('my_model'), except=["SOME_DATE_FIELD"]) }}
from {{ ref('my_model') }}
),
...
```

Note:

1. to use `dbt_utils.star()` you first need to install dbt_utils as a package in your project. See [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management)
2. in dbt you really shouldn't select from `my_db.my_schema.my_table` directly. That table should either be a model or a source, and you should use either the `ref` or `source` macro to select from it, so dbt can build a DAG:

```sql
from {{ ref("my_table") }}
```

or

```sql
from {{ source("my_source", "my_table") }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that I shouldn't use `my_db.my_schema.my_table` directly, it just did it to anonymized it. Is there any way I can avoid hardcoding the column name? All the examples provided use `except (SOME_DATE_FIELD)`, but I would like avoiding that.

Thanks!

Comment: not really. You could build a list in jinja with your field names, like `{% set fields_to_transform = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] %}`, and then use that list in the macro: `{{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('my_model'), except=fields_to_transform) }}`, but it'll depend on your use case if you can build the `fields_to_transform` list dynamically (and you won't be able to do it by parsing the query with dbt)